# Facebook Marketing API reach of post

Tags: facebook-ads-api

is the Facebook Ads API the right API to look at when I want to get the estimated reach of a post (posted in the name of a page) on Facebook?
I would need to set location, radius, gender, budget and get the reach - I am looking for a general direction to look at or good examples in PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's the direct [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reachestimate/v2.3) to help page that explains reach estimate.

Comment: Thanks, I know that page but I am looking for examples and a hint what those numbers mean. I get strange results which do not relate to values shown on facebooks UI.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the difference in reach estimate between Ads Manager UI and the API? I just posted a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847594/is-there-any-relationship-between-the-reach-in-ads-manager-and-in-the-ads-api) on that.

Comment: Where can you put the budget in this api?