# Is there any relationship between the reach estimate in Ads Manager and in the Ads API?

Tags: facebook, geolocation, facebook-ads-api

I just noticed that the numbers given by Ads API and the Ads Manager are wildly different. For instance, when searching for the French speakers in the city of Anderlecht, Belgium, the Ads Manager shows *44,000* people and the Ads API gives me the number *12,000*.

See the screenshot of the Ads Manager UI and of the curl script calling  below:

[image: Audience reach in Ads Manager]

```
curl -G  -q \
  -d 'targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"cities":    
      [{"key":"171194"}]},"locales":[1003]}' \
  -d 'access_token=XYZ' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_000000000000000/reachestimate
```

The number `1003` in locales corresponds to "French (All)" and the number `171194` is cities corresponds to "Anderlecht".

What explains such a difference in reach estimations?

Here's the JSON output from the above script:

```
{"users": 12000, "bid_estimations": [{
  "unsupported": false, "location": 3, "cpa_min": 66,
     "cpa_median": 107, "cpa_max": 140, "cpc_min": 19, 
     "cpc_median": 33, "cpc_max": 43, "cpm_min": 10, 
     "cpm_median": 42, "cpm_max": 106 }],
  "estimate_ready": true, "data": {"users": 12000,
"bid_estimations": [{
   "unsupported": false,  "location": 3, "cpa_min": 66,
   "cpa_median": 107, "cpa_max": 140, "cpc_min": 19, 
   "cpc_median": 33, "cpc_max": 43, "cpm_min": 10, 
   "cpm_median": 42, "cpm_max": 106}],
"estimate_ready": true}}
```

Comment: They should be broadly similar, but unless you use web dev tools to see the call being made by Ads Manager (or Power Editor) and compare it yo your own it't hard to be sure you're comparing the exact same set of targeting data (even though, yes it looks the same based on your screenshot here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I did look into the AJAX calls made by Ads Manager, and it looks like the default location_types attribute is "home" while the Ads Manager uses "home" and "recent". That's the difference.

```
curl -G  -q \
  -d 'targeting_spec={"geo_locations":{"cities":    
      [{"key":"171194"}],"location_types":["recent", "home"]},"locales":[1003]}' \
  -d 'access_token=XYZ' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_000000000000000/reachestimate
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on mikhailian's answer, you may also need to specify the following:

```
targeting_spec: {
    .....geolocation as above....
    publisher_platforms: ['facebook', 'instagram', 'audience_network'],
    facebook_positions: ['feed', 'instant_article', 'instream_video', 'right_hand_column', 'suggested_video'],
    instagram_positions: ['stream'],
    messenger_positions: [],
    device_platforms: ['mobile', 'desktop'],
    audience_network_positions: ['classic', 'instream_video']
}
```